# Installing JDK 1.5 on OS X Lion

Tags: android, osx-lion, java-5

How to install JDK 1.5 in Lion?

I need it to compile Android 2.2. I followed the instruction mentioned in this site, but still couldn't get it to show on Java Preferences.
[installing jdk 1.5](http://chxor.chxo.com/post/183013153/installing-java-1-5-on-snow-leopard)

Comment: You can find it [here](http://chxor.chxo.com/post/7891964025/java-1-5-in-os-x-lion).

Answer (score 2):

I made small script that can automate the install without requiring you to install any other software. This jdk install part of the script is based on works from this blog: http://www.s-seven.net/zend_5x_lion

1. Download the leopard java5 update : http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1359
2. In the same folder download the script : https://gist.github.com/1163008
3. In a terminal make it executable : `chmod +x the_script.sh`
4. Run the script as root (using sudo) : `sudo the_script.sh`
5. If everything ran without a hitch the Java preference window should list the java 5 runtime

Original instructions in french (there's a translation button) : http://blog.arkey.fr/2012/07/30/script-pour-installer-le-jdk-5-sur-macosx-lion/

**EDIT** : The script has been updated to work on Mountain Lion as well. The script can download the Java 5 update too.

Comment: Brice, the url is broken. I used this one http://blog.arkey.fr/2012/07/30/script-pour-installer-le-jdk-5-sur-macosx-lion/

Comment: @David Thanks, the link is fixed. (The date in the URL changed because due to the update in the post)